# GDM two, independent login screens

Tags: linux, xorg, gdm

Is there a way to have the GDM login screen appear on multiple ttys at startup? I should be able to operate each independently---start different desktop environments, etc.

I'm using GDM 3.38.2.1 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Using GDM on multiple ttys is supported *only* for purposes of user switching. GDM explicitly does not support running multiple sessions for the same user.

GDM starts login screens (greeters) on demand – you can run `gdmflexiserver` to ask GDM to start a new greeter, where a different user can log in side-by-side to your session; some desktop environments used to have a direct menu item to switch users. However, no matter what tty you use to log in, GDM will always switch you back to the same tty that already contains your first graphical session.